# How to create a dataframe from mutiple table made from table$ function?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with column names ag,bg,cg,dg,eg. I made count of variables in each column using `df$` function.

```
table(df$ag)
table(df$bg)
table(df$cg)
table(df$dg)
table(df$eg)
```

and the output was:

```
High      Low Moderate 
 648      628      628 

High      Low Moderate 
 648      628      628 

High      Low Moderate 
 648      628      628 

High      Low Moderate 
 648      628      628 

High      Low Moderate 
 648      628      628
```

I want to create another datafrmae with these values as :

```
High    Low Moderate    Group
648     628 628         ag
648     628 628         bg
648     628 628         cg
648     628 628         dg
648     628 628         eg
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(t(sapply(df[paste0(letters[1:5], 'g')], table)))`

Comment: ` undefined columns selected` shows me an error

Comment: `df[paste0(letters[1:5], 'g')]` this code extracts columns `ag` to `cg` from `df`, right? If not, you should check whether these column names exist in `df` or not.

Comment: are there any other way for giving the  names not by `ag, bg.. eg`. My columns are :  `Ribbon, Paint, Girls, Boys, Teacher`

Comment: @batman  `as.data.frame(t(sapply(df[,c('Ribbon','Paint','Girls','Boys','Teacher')], table)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
new = as.data.frame(t(sapply(df[,c('ag','bg','cg','dg','eg')], table)))
```

new

```
    High    Low Moderate
   <int>    <int>   <int>
ag  648      628    628
bg  648      628    628
cg  648      628    628
dg  648      628    628
eg  648      628    628
```

Comment: Hi, what's the difference between your answer and my comment and what is `dplyr` loaded for?

Comment: the op requires custom selection: not this one `[paste0(letters[1:5], 'g')`